# How to return multiple times same component but with independant state?

Tags: reactjs, key, state

Hi guys in react i want to do something like render 2 times a component in same render function like this

```
const Main()=>{

const [names, setNames] = useState([]);
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(-1);

return(
    <Component1 name={names[selected].name}
                setName={setNames}/>

    <Component1 name={names[selected].name}
                setName={setNames}/>
)
}
```

This where i passed `setNames` from `Main()` to `Component1` to handle state
and pass `names`  from Main() then map it in select of `Component1`

```
<StyledSelect
       ml="10px"
       onChange={(e) => {
       setName(e.target.value);
        value={name}>
       {names.map(({ name}) => {
         return (
                <option key={name} value={name}>
                  {name}
                </option>
                );
         })}
```

my component has an html select that has names in it, when i choose one it trigger a   it in database and retrieve name data (age, location), the problem is when i select name on my second Component1, it will also select the same name and retrieve same name data on my first Component1, and i want them to be independent. How ?

I tried to put key like that

```
return(
    <Component1 key="compare" name={name}/>
    <Component1 key="compared" name={name}/>
)
```

but nothing changes

Thanks

Comment: Please share what you have done so far clearly. This is unclear

Comment: @SriVineeth i edited, i just tried to add a key because saw somewhere that is helps to make each component independent but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

This question is worded incorrectly (this has nothing to do with state and everything to do with props and how React renders) and is missing information, but here are a few pieces of information that might help:

- Keys don't change anything on the front-end; they are a tool React uses to improve performance on the back-end. [Click here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) to read the docs for more information on keys and how React uses them.
- React components are JavaScript functions and can therefore only return 1 thing. The code sample you shared would not work in React (or JavaScript). In order to return multiple items, it is possible to wrap them in an array or a React Fragment. Consider this example:

```
    render() {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <ChildA />
          <ChildB />
          <ChildC />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
```

If you want to make the dropdowns different in appearance and/or functionality, the `name` prop will need to be different. Right now, both instances of `Component1` are being given the same `name` property, which is why they probably look and behave identically.

Answer (score 0):

(i would like can comment but i can't)

i am not sure (i must see the complete code) but i think that:

```
return(
    <Component1 key="compare" name={name}/>
    <Component1 key="compared" name={name}/>
)
```

must be

```
return(
    <Component1 key="compare" name={name1}/>
    <Component1 key="compared" name={name2}/>
)
```

this way they don't share the same variable

Comment: If you only have 2 components so create two variables (props) name1 and name2

Answer (score 0):

Where is it that you're making the call and setting the name? Since you're passing the same prop name to both of them they will be the same.
Either you set name inside Component1 itself or you make a different state for each Component1.

Comment: Move const [names, setNames] = useState([]); from main to Component1 and remove the passed name props inside Main return.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation but in my case it was an id that I needed to make unique.
I had component that rendered a list of controlled ToggleButtons in a group from React Bootstrap.   I wanted to display 2 lists of the buttons, both containing the same list of names that could be selected under different categories.  In the end I had to set the id NOT the key. I originally had set it as the index of the list.. but of course, both lists had identical indexes so only the first one had state and pressing the 2nd list would select or deselect from the first list.  to solve it I passed an id down through props and then appended the id to the index to make it unique.

```
      function ToggleList({ variant = 'secondary', vertical = true, ...restProps }) {
  var items = restProps.list ? restProps.list.map((subject, index) => {
    return <ToggleButton
      className="mb-2"
      size="sm"
      id={`${restProps.id}-${index}`}
      type="checkbox"
      value={subject}
      variant={variant}>
      {subject}
    </ToggleButton>;
  }) : '';
```